# Issue while calling mutlile API in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, api, alamofire

I have two classes.Class A and Class B. In class A there is table view.When i tap on cell in class A i call first api to save the data `/saveData` & on response of first api i call another api `getData`.I call these API in background.Now when i move to class A i call the another API on `viewDidLoad()`.I call this in foreground .Now i want that the API of class A should not effect the class B.

Please tell what is the best way to do that.

i tried `DispatchGroup` but did not work for me.

```
    func saveInBackground(parameter : [String : AnyObject]?) -> Void {

        let group = DispatchGroup()
        group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)){

            let apiManager = APIHandler(baseURL: Constants.API.baseURL, APIVersion: "")

            apiManager.requestOfBgMethod(.post, path: Constants.API.Name.addGeneralField.completePath, parameters: parameter, encoding: .url, headers: nil, apiSuccess: { (result) in
                //update user
                self.copyUser = User(copyFrom: self.user)
                self.saveCVResponse(result: result)
                //fetch data in background
                Utility.sharedInstance.updateCVdata(cvManager: self.cvManager)
            }, apiFailure: { (error) in

            })
        }

//        DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.background).async {
//            
//
//        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DispatchSemaphore` and a Singleton instance to make API calling one by one:

```
class ApiHelper {
    static let shardInstance = ApiHelper()
    private let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1) //one task allowed at a time
    private let apiManager = APIHandler(baseURL: Constants.API.baseURL, APIVersion: "")

    func saveInBackground(parameter : [String : AnyObject]?) -> Void {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async { [unowned self] in
            self.semaphore.wait() //lock

            apiManager.requestOfBgMethod(.post, path: Constants.API.Name.addGeneralField.completePath, parameters: parameter, encoding: .url, headers: nil, apiSuccess: { (result) in
                //.......
                self.semaphore.signal()  //unlock
            }, apiFailure: { (error) in
                self.semaphore.signal()  //unlock
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Use it in Class A and Class B, they will not be effected each other:

```
ApiHelper.shardInstance.saveInBackground(parameter: nil)
```

Comment: For this case i have to change the whole API structure which is very complex & time consuming.Because the background & forground api does not use the same method

Comment: Are you able to modify class `APIHandler `?  Maybe this class should provide  a Singleton to do this.

Comment: Or you could define a global variable of `DispatchSemaphore`, and directly use it in your `saveInBackground` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use global `DispatchSemaphore` without Singleton:

In class A or class B or somewhere, define a global semaphore out of class:

```
let semaphoreGlobal = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1) //one task at a time

//ignore following, just an example.
class AnyClass {
    //......
}
```

And your method become:

```
func saveInBackground(parameter : [String : AnyObject]?) -> Void {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
        semaphoreGlobal.wait() //wait if semaphore is 0. Else, set semaphore to 0 and continue.

        //remember: the variable 'apiManager' should not be a local one.
        apiManager.requestOfBgMethod(.post, path: Constants.API.Name.addGeneralField.completePath, parameters: parameter, encoding: .url, headers: nil, apiSuccess: { (result) in
            //.......
            semaphoreGlobal.signal()  //set semaphore to 1, means allowing one of other tasks stops waiting.
        }, apiFailure: { (error) in
            semaphoreGlobal.signal()  //set semaphore to 1
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: What will happen in this case ? Will it wait for other api called from any other method ? Should i use same semophare object in multiple classes. I don't unserstand how to follow your approach

Comment: In this case,  in this method and any other methods, only ONE block of the codes between `.wait()` and `.signal()` will be executed at a time.The others will wait until previous block send signal by `signal()`. Yes, you should use same semophare object in multiple classes, that's why it's global.

Comment: And I updated the comments in answer for your information.

Comment: How can i use the global without singleton.Becuase i will not able to acess semophare object in that case

Comment: Define the object anywhere, just not in a class. Then it's global.

Comment: ok so i declare in my any class & but how does it know that some API has to wait because i don't use saveInBackground for all API.I have created different methods for that ?

Comment: The object `semaphoreGlobal` knows when to wait, when to continue. All of APIs that you don't want to call them at same time, should use a same global `DispatchSemaphore ` object. And I updated the answer to give an example shows where to declare the `semaphoreGlobal`.